# What is jQuery Mobile?. Is it capable to Create Games for Android?

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, jquery-mobile

Please tell following: -
1. What is jquery mobile?.
2. Knowledge of which language is required to work with it?.
3. Whether its purpose is just to create web sites, which looks good on all smart phones?.
4. **Is it capable to create Games for Android?** If yes, which tools are required for that?.

*Comments to Responders*

@ hunter: Thanks, your Quoted introduction properly guides. Regarding "pain of creating Apps for different Smart phones", I want to say that with Phonegap, an App can be deployed to all major Smart phones with some code tweaking, as I read here. The referred Javasript Games are also good.

@ altcognito: Thanks.

@ Nick Campion: I am talking about those Type of high profile rich UI games, which are created with java for Android. Whether such type of games can be created with jQuery Mobile?

@ BandsOnABudget: thanks

@ Knossos: thanks and please tell, are you talking about browser based web games?

Comment: @user514892 If you have comments for the others, please post them as comments to their answers, or (if the comment is too lengthy) append it to your original question. I've migrated your comments from a false-answer below into your question for you this time.

Answer (score 11):

1) jQuery mobile is a javascript framework, using jQuery, geared toward mobile devices

> A unified user interface system across all popular mobile device platforms, built on the rock-solid jQuery and jQuery UI foundation. Its lightweight code is built with progressive enhancement, and has a flexible, easily themeable design.

http://jquerymobile.com/

2) Knowledge of JavaScript would be nice

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp

3) It would seem so

> jQuery mobile framework takes the "write less, do more" mantra to the next level: Instead of writing unique apps for each mobile device or OS, the jQuery mobile framework will allow you to design a single highly branded and customized web application that will work on all popular smartphone and tablet platforms.

4) No, but you could certainly build web-based games with JavaScript. To develop applications for Android-based devices you should download their SDK and go through their [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html).

http://developer.android.com/index.html

---

And this is why developing for mobile devices is such a pain. You can either build an application for a specific device on a specific platform (iPhone, Android, etc) or you can build a web-based application that can't have the deep-device integration that can greatly enhance the UI.

---

Here's [a list of JavaScript-based Games](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/25-amazing-javascript-games-some-fun-and-inspiration/), just to give you some idea what JavaScript alone is capable of. *(a lot of the links are broken)*

Some good ones:

- [Digg Attack](http://www.pixastic.com/labs/digg_attack/)
- [Sudoku](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/game_sudoku/game_sudoku.html)

But, as you can see, you're not going to blow anyone away, but Digg Attack is very impressive for what it's working with.

Comment: I think in particular on the games question it's all about optimization. Clearly the GUI is going to be most efficient using their SDK. As time moves on, browsers (even on a handheld) will probably have a WebGL API powerful enough to create games. But right now. No way.

Comment: Its too broad to be answered.  What type of games?  You could certainly make a crossword puzzle or sudoku game.  You probably could not make a mario clone.  Just depends what type of game it is.

Answer (score 2):

have your browsed this site? http://jquerymobile.com/

the "short" answer is that it's the javascript that allows you to build HTML/JS driven web applications that have a "look and feel" of a native app. They run within a web browser so they are platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding, is that jQuery mobile is superset of jQuery (which is a Javascript library for web development).

This mobile version seems to be optimized for creating buttons for mobile device.s

It is just to create websites. You can create games with it, but a better understanding of Javascript would be required for that.

Information: [link text](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/)

Comment: Actually jQuery Mobile is a superset of jQuery.  It adds additional capabilities for mobile while retaining the complete jQuery.

Comment: There is a question stating just that and it was already explained! Don't write such things without reading anything except frameworts' names, please.